# How can I solve a far away stacking Freestyle line

Tags: freestyle

Im a beginner to use blender for comic

[image]

i try a way to make line on faraway object to be small but it still have a result like this. their are the way or some easy method to make a stacking line look doesn't black like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're already doing this, apologies if so.

You can assign a Distance from Camera modifier to the line thickness in the View Layer Properties tab > Line Style panel.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

- You might have to use separate Line Sets for other features whose
  detail you want to preserve in the distance.
- You can assign the same modifier to Alpha, making the lines more transparent in the distance -  a possible alternative.
- As you can see, depending on the resolution of your rendered image, at some thickness, sampling/antialiasing takes over. This might be before your set 0 point; you'll have to tweak the curve / base thickness accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can just exclude some edges from the Freestyle line set.

1. Select your edges
2. Mark them as Freestyle (*Edit > Mark Freestyle Edge*)
3. Check ***✓*** Edge Mark and the little **`×`** to prevent marked edges from being drawn

[image]