# How can i variate the size of the outline on Freestyle?

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I added an outline for the render with the Freestyle option on Blender 2.8, but when i zoom-in/out the camera, the line tends to maintain the same size, how can i make it change a little when i move the camera? (making the line not that bold when the camera is far away, for example)

Also, how can i 'choose' how much influence it will get? for instance, the shoes look weird in the last picture...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). @RobinBetts provided a very useful answer to a similar question https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165907/78972

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot!

Comment: If you want you can put it as an answer, it truly helped for what i wanted!

Comment: Glad to be of help :). Consider marking your question as a duplicate of the linked one. To keep the site nice and tidy :).

Comment: Thank you again! have a nice day.